# Не вносятся данные в mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Одно значение прошло и записалось, но дальше ничего. Соединение с БД есть, но данные не заносятся. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"  type="text/css">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="form.php" method="post" name="forma">
<fieldset>
<label for="first_name">Имя:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="name" size="30"><br/>
<label for="last_name">Text:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="text" size="30"><br/>
</fieldset>
<br/>
<fieldset>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить данные"><br/>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")//параметры в скобках ("хост", "имя пользователя", "пароль")
or die("<p>Ошибка подключения к базе данных! " . mysql_error() . "</p>");

mysql_select_db("mysitekatya")//параметр в скобках ("имя базы, с которой соединяемся")
 or die("<p>Ошибка выбора базы данных! ". mysql_error() . "</p>");
?>

<?php 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$text = $_REQUEST['text'];

$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO date (name, text)" .
"VALUES('{$name}', '{$text}');";
mysql_query($insert_sql);
?>
```

Comment: Расширение `mysql_` уже выброшено на помойку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "mysitekatya";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name) or 
           die("<p>Невозможно подключиться к СУБД: " . mysqli_error() . ". Ошибка произошла в строке " . __LINE__ . "</p>");;
    mysqli_query($connect,"SET NAMES utf8");    // чтоб SQL понимал запросы на русском языке
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

if (isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO `date` (`name`, `text`)
                VALUES('$name', '$text');";
    mysqli_query($connect, $insert_sql);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"  type="text/css">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="forma">
<fieldset>
<label for="first_name">Имя:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="name" size="30"><br/>
<label for="last_name">Text:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="text" size="30"><br/>
</fieldset>
<br/>
<fieldset>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="save" value="Отправить данные"><br/>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85852/discussion-on-answer-by-assasin2-----mysql).